# How to upload a image from local system to rich text field using visualforce page?

Tags: visualforce

How to upload a image from local system to rich text field using visualforce page?.i need to upload a image from local system selected image and save to rich text field directly.can anybody help me on this......

Answer (score 1):

If you are binding to a rich text field on an object, you can instead use

`<apex:inputField value="{!your.FieldName}"/>`

This will give you access to the Salesforce rich text editor, and allow image uploads inline with text.

Answer (score 0):

This may show a image in RichText Field with VF and Apex.

**Apex Class :**

```
public class ImagInsertionIntoRichText
{

 public String naam{get;set;}
 public ID folderid{get;set;}
 public Blob file{get;set;}

 public void insrt()
 {

 Document d= new Document();

 d.name = naam;
 d.body=file; // body field in document object which holds the file.
 d.folderid='00l90000000inFEAAY'; //folderid where the document will be stored insert d;
 insert d;

 }
}
```

**VF Page :**

```
<apex:page controller="ImagInsertionIntoRichText">
 <apex:form>
  <apex:outputLabel value="Document Name"></apex:outputLabel>
  <apex:inputText id="name" value="{!naam}"/>

  <apex:outputLabel value="Upload Document"></apex:outputLabel>
  <apex:inputfile value="{!file}"></apex:inputfile>

  <apex:commandButton value="Save" action="{!insrt}" id="save"/>
 </apex:form>
</apex:page>
```

Comment: I need to insert a custom object  and i need to insert the picture in rich text field

Comment: Can you check this link: http://ankit-rustagi.blogspot.com/2012/10/to-insert-image-into-rich-text-area.html

Comment: Yes. I refered this link and test my dev org then I post here. @SantanuBoral